# Create git archive of subtree with all changes in zip

Tags: git, hook, pre-commit

I am attempting to create a zipfile that contains all of the files, changed or committed, into a zip archive.  The reason for this is that we have a downloadable example project for customers.  When any changes occur in the the example code, we need to update the zip file that exists in the public facing web app.

I thought it would be good to use a git pre-commit hook to accomplish this. However, I am fairly new to git and don't know shell scripting.  I got the following pre-commit script to create an archive of the files that I want in the location that I want:

## !C:/Program\ Files/Git/usr/bin/sh.exe

REF_APP_PATH="Source/CodeExamples/DataServiceReferenceApp"

if git diff --cached --name-only | grep --quiet "$REF_APP_PATH"
then

echo "Updating changed files in DataServiceReferenceApp.zip"

git archive --format=zip  --output=Source/WebApi/Api/Downloads/test.zip HEAD:Source/CodeExamples/DataServiceReferenceApp
fi

exit 0

The problem is, all the files are from the prior commit and not the changed files that are being checked in. I want to archive the old and new in the correct tree structure, then commit the changed plus the updated zip.

Anyone have any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a post-commit hook instead, just rename the hook.

> After the entire commit process is completed, the post-commit hook runs. It doesn’t take any parameters, but you can easily get the last commit by running git log -1 HEAD. Generally, this script is used for notification or something similar.

When you use a pre-commit hook your changes are still in the index and HEAD still points to the last completed commit (you can get your changes with `git diff-index --cached HEAD`).

> The pre-commit hook is run first, before you even type in a commit message.

Comment: I don't see how this helps me archive. I would need to get the commit id and git log -1 HEAD doesn't return that.

Comment: Also, I only want to do the archive if files have changed.  I don't see how your suggestion will give me the files in the specific folder that changed with the last commit.  I don't want the entire commit and I only want to update the archive if certain files changed.  I have already tried post commit.  I can create the archive if I do it every time.  What that ends up doing is creating a new file that needs to be committed after every commit.. That isn't feasible.